# ionic tabs color dosen't show correctly

Tags: css, ionic-framework

in my application i have ionic tab . but the color on my devise and simulator dosen't work correctly.for example base on image below :

[image: tabs problem]

my tab background must be yellow with white icons but it show white background white background with yellow icons.

my code is :

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">app</h1>
</div>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-energized tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="a" icon="ion-document-text" ui-sref="app.book">
        <ion-nav-view name="a"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="b" icon="ion-pie-graph" ui-sref="app.chart">
        <ion-nav-view name="b"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="c" icon="ion-playstation" ui-sref="app.games">
        <ion-nav-view name="c"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="d" icon="ion-gear-a" ui-sref="app.settings">
        <ion-nav-view name="d"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab>
        <ion-nav-view name="f"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab>
        <ion-nav-view name="g"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab>
        <ion-nav-view name="h"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-pan>
```

so how to fix this problem for showing tabs with yellow background. i also try with other ionic framework colors and get same problem.

Comment: Works for me at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/OPNawX

Comment: Yes . it works for me in desktop browser.but in genymotion simulator and Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo and Samsung Galaxy Neo and htc dosen't work.

Comment: Hmm.. In nexus 4 and 10 it shows correctly. What browser and version are you using in your devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it just by changing the order of items inside attribute "class" as follow:
`<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">`

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` to the CSS style.